# R looping through 20 million rows

Tags: r, loops

I have a **.txt** File called `Sales_2015` which has almost **1GB** of info. The file has the following columns:

```
AREA|WEEKNUMBER|ITEM|STORE_NO|SALES|UNITS_SOLD
10GUD| W01_2015 |0345| 023234 |1200 | 12
```

The File´s **colClasses** is: `c(rep("character",4),rep("numeric",2))`

What I want to do is separate the 1GB file into pieces so it becomes faster to read. The number of `.txt` files I want to end up with will be defined by the number of **AREAS** I have. (Which is the first column).

So I have the following variables:

```
Sales <- read.table(paste(RUTAC,"/Sales_2015.txt",sep=""),sep="|",header=T, quote="",comment.char="",colClasses=c("character",rep("numeric",3)))

Areas <- c("10GUD","10CLJ","10DZV",..................) #There is 52 elements
```

I Want to end up with 52 `.txt` files which names are for instance:

`2015_10GUD.txt` (Which will only include entire rows of info from 1GB file that contain `10GUD` in the `AREA` Column)

`2015_10CLJ.txt` (Which will only include entire rows of info from 1GB file that contain `10CLJ`)

I know this question is very similar to others but the difference is that I am working with a up to 20 million rows...Can anybody help me get this done with some sort of loop such as **repeat** or something else?

Comment: when you read the 20-million row `data.frame` in the first place, perhaps you should try using `fread{data.table}`, which is waaaay faster than `read.table`

Comment: `fread` is pretty much magic. It can probably do this in like 3 seconds.

Comment: Not sure hat the downvotes are for. You might have explained what sort of hardware resoures we are expected to have. That put serious constraints on what is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to use a loop. The simplest and fastest way to do this is probably using `data.table`. I strongly recommend you use development version of data.table 1.9.7. so you can use the super fast `fwrite` function to write `.csv` files. Go [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for install instructions.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Sales_2015)[, fwrite(.SD, paste0("Sales_2015_", ID,".csv")), 
                              by = AREA, .SDcols=names(Sales_2015)]
```

also, I would recommend you read your data using `fread{data.table}`, which is waaaay faster than `read.table`

```
Sales_2015 <- fread("C:/address to your file/Sales_2015.txt")
```

Comment: thanks for the edit @Arun, the code is much more elegant and intuitive now